# Cordova plugin background mode for iOS device

Tags: android, ios, cordova, background-process, ionic5

I am creating a hybrid (android/iOS) app that should support downloading multiple files and processing them in the background. I am using cordova-plugin-background-mode for supporting my app. I cant find any other alternatives to support background downloading and processing. I have completed the app for the android part and I got it to work perfectly, but before submitting it to the play store and apple store I found that apple doesn't accept the usage of this plugin since it uses an audio file to play at 0 volume (I read this at this link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-plugin-background-mode-rejected-by-ios-remove-the-audio-setting/69864)

Also, This was provided at the GitHub page(https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) of the plugin

**Store Compliance**

> Infinite background tasks are not official supported on most mobile operation systems and >thus not compliant with public store vendors. A successful submssion isn't garanteed.

Use the plugin by your own risk!

I am using Ionic5 and capacitor.

Is there any way to fix this issue or is there any other plugin available for iOS to support my app.

Also for android, many comments said that android accepted this plugin. If there are any new policies updates please suggest me a workaround.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For iOS you will need to use [`BGProcessingTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtask)

Comment: @Paulw11 i have built the rest of the app with ionic. is it possible to integrate with BGProcessingTask?

Comment: There must be some way to integrate with native code in Ionic, but I'm afraid I don't know anything about that environment.